# MeasureString() doesn't return enough width

Tags: c#, label, measurestring

I have the following code to create a `Label` on a `PictureBox`:

```
Label l = new Label();
l.Text = _name;
l.Size = CreateGraphics().MeasureString(_name, l.Font).ToSize();
l.BackColor = Color.White;
```

but the label is always dropping the last character. If I add a character to the call:

```
l.Size = CreateGraphics().MeasureString(_name+".", l.Font).ToSize();
```

it works fine, but that doesn't feel right.

There seems to be some white space just before the text in the label, but `Padding` is set to 0. How can I fix this the correct way?

Comment: Do you need to size the label? is there something wrong with the AutoSize property? Would you be better not using a label at all (since it's on a picture box you could draw directly to the picture box)

Comment: You are right, the `AutoSize` property works fine. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, the Label control requires TextRenderer.MeasureText() since it draws text with TextRenderer.DrawText(), not Graphics.DrawString().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you use the `AutoSize` property?

`MeasureString` is notoriously inaccurate, though normally it returns a size bigger than you'd expect:

> The MeasureString method is designed for use with individual strings and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string to allow for overhanging glyphs. Also, the DrawString method adjusts glyph points to optimize display quality and might display a string narrower than reported by MeasureString. To obtain metrics suitable for adjacent strings in layout (for example, when implementing formatted text), use the MeasureCharacterRanges method or one of the MeasureString methods that takes a StringFormat, and pass GenericTypographic. Also, ensure the TextRenderingHint for the Graphics is AntiAlias.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx

Answer (score 3):

ToSize() truncates values of the SizeF to the next lower integer values.

So, to avoid losses you can do something like that:

```
l.Size = (CreateGraphics().MeasureString(_name, l.Font) + new SizeF(1, 0)).ToSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something as simple as getting the size wrong when you declare your font compared to the UI font size?

Comment: I don't understand, can you elaborate? I updated my question a little to show that I create the label just before.